# Paste values from a vector to column names in R

Tags: r

i want to paste the values from a vector to the column names of a data frame. Suppose that the file has 4 columns and the tmp2 vector has 4 values.
The for loop works perfectly fine(the new colnames is the value of tmp and the value of tmp2 together) but i want to try the same with an apply family function

```
tmp <- colnames(file)

tmp2 <- c(1,2,3,4)

for(i in 1:length(tmp)){

names(tmp)[i] = paste(tmp[i], tmp2[i])

}
```

For example something like this

```
sapply(tmp,function(x,y){

names(x)<-paste(x,y)
},y=tmp2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. If `tmp` is `tmp <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)` and `tmp2` is `tmp2 <- c("w","x","y","z")` what do you want as the final result for the names of `tmp`?

Comment: Column names of tmp would be
aw bx cy dz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any `loop`. The `paste` is vectorised too. As I have understood OP wants to suffix all column with a sequence number.

Just try:

```
names(file) <- paste(names(file),1:ncol(file), sep = "")
# A1 B2  C3
# 1  A  1 101
# 2  B  2 102
# 3  C  3 103
# 4  D  4 104
# 5  E  5 105
```

**Data**

```
file <- data.frame(A = "A":"E", B = 1:5, C = 101:105)
file
# A B   C
# 1 A 1 101
# 2 B 2 102
# 3 C 3 103
# 4 D 4 104
# 5 E 5 105
```

Comment: Actually i want to paste to the column names the values of a vector,
In your example for the three columns i would like to add to each colname a value from a different vector for example
tmp<-c("a","b","c")
# Aa Bb  Cc

Comment: @Skampak Then try this: `names(file) <- paste(names(file), tmp, sep = "")`

Answer (score 1):

`names(tmp)=mapply(x=tmp,y=tmp2,function(x,y)paste(x,y))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it `data.table` way which is not computationally expensive.

```
library(data.table)
file <- data.table(x=(1:3),y=letters[1:3],z=(1),w=letters[1:3])
tmp2 <- paste(colnames(file),rep(1:nrow(file)))
setnames(file,1:ncol(file),tmp2)
```

EDIT: If you want to suffix `colnames` with sequence numbers, as mentioned by @MKR